# Can not open HTML file in visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Suddenly faced a problem, I cannot open HTML file in visual studio 2013.

Here is my solution:
[image]

When I make double click on HtmlPage.html I get this massage:

[image]

I tried to make exclude from project and include to project.But it didn't helped me.

While other files with I can open as usual.

If I close the current solution and open another I still get the same problem.

Any idea why I cant open the html file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2013 - Operation Could Not Be Completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523510/vs2013-operation-could-not-be-completed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click right button and select "Open with" option and after select html-editor. It should help.

Comment: Is it happens with any html files or only with this file?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

In your web config you should have the above 3 lines. You should replace the
value "2.0.?.?" with "3.0.0.0" and you should be fine.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.?.?" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: I dont have <appSettings> in my webconfig file

Comment: Insert those lines then.

Comment: Unrecognized element.I get when I try to builld after inserting element above.