# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013: Jquery debugger's cannot continue running the process. The operation could not be completed

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

we are getting following message very frequently during jQuery debugging, is there any fix available for this? After this Visual Studio has to be restarted to debug again!

Just went through multiple posts like [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2320a943-d52d-437a-abec-6f1e9f929b52/debugger-error-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed?forum=vsdebug) and [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2008/06/07/getting-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-retry-should-be-performed-while-debugging-in-visual-studio.aspx) and [this for vs 2005](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/06/07/getting-quot-unable-to-step-the-operation-could-not-be-completed-a-retry-should-be-performed-quot-while-debugging-in-visual-studio.aspx) and [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079466/visual-studio-the-operation-could-not-be-completed) , still this problem exits?

```
---------------------------
**Microsoft Visual Studio**
---------------------------
The debugger cannot continue running the process. 
The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed.
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing debugging ASP.NET MVC App.

Comment: I' having the same issue. And I wonder, where is the retry button? Does it exist?