# VS 2013 giving The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer on Razor views

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS 2015 version on my system. I already had Visual studio 2013 update 4 installed on my machine. But now, whenever I try to open any cshtml ( razor view) in VS 2013, I get following error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### The operation could not be completed. Invalid pointer

### OK

Please suggest me its solution.

Comment: To add to this, as a workaround I am able to open up the file using "open with" and selecting the xml editor. I can then open it up regularly so long as the XML editor is open for that file. However this does not give any intellisense for the razor view

Comment: It is a very low-level COM error, E_POINTER, could be anything.  You'd normally put add-ins at the top of the suspect list but I don't use any and still see these non-descript COM errors a lot.  Also after Update 1, VS2015 is a massive bag-o-bugs.  DevDiv's new focus on agile development appears to have included firing all their test engineers, they are not agile enough.  Restarting it has so far always resolved the problem, I'm keeping my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 78):

For anyone arriving here after installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and then updating some packages, here is what fixed it for me:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Re-open Visual Studio

I was getting this error message in VS2015 and the fix worked for me, so it seems to apply to 2013 and 2015.

I found the solution on another Stack Overflow question: [Visual Studio 2015 Broken Razor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense).

Comment: I'm giving this the bounty because this is probably what ended up happening through my steps, and it seems to have worked for others.

Comment: This was the fix for me.  Worked in VS 2015 too.

Comment: Worked for me. When you delete that folder you get these dialogues which you've probably noticed from time to time, something in there probably gets messed up:
Scanning new and updated MEF components...
Writing component cache...
Composing MEF graph...

Comment: Deleting ComponentModelCache solved this issue. Why did it work though? Anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 fixed this for me:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: It only occurred for me after installing update 1. I think ultimately the solution is probably something to do with clearing a cache

Comment: This just happened to me after update 1 as well. Did you find a solution @mirhagk?

Comment: My solution is below. I closed VS, opened up dev tools and ran `devenv /SafeMode` then opened the file successfully. Then I closed it and opened it normally

Comment: I tried that with no luck. Had to delete ComponentModelCache per my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to delete Solution User Options (.Suo) File. In my case it was the evil and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ended up fixing it, but I closed Visual Studio and opened up developer tools, and ran `devenv /SafeMode` which starts it with no extensions installed. I then navigated and opened up the solution in the instance and it worked. It complained about source control bindings and removed those (This solution used to be in a TFS project and now it's in a git tfs project). Then after saving it and closing visual studio I was able to re-open the solution from file explorer.

I'm not sure if it was the devenv or the source control bindings that fixed it, or just restarting visual studio for the umpteenth time, but it appears to work now.

Comment: FWIW, I did try this (safemode) and have any complaints about bindings. Still got the pointer error in safemode as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and I have tried the following with NO SUCCES

- “%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG” to something
  else. I changed it to VS7DEBUG1.
- Delete the content of
  %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
- Installed Servicing Update
  (KB3110221) -
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/26/servicing-update-available-for-visual-studio-update-1/
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetuserdata
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
  /resetsettings

**I finally uninstalled visual studio 2015. Restarted and installed it again and then it worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just a matter of **closing Visual Studio 2015** and **then open again.**

I have had this happen on a few machines.

This does happen

```
"Have you tried to delete the "Your_Solution_FileName.suo" file?"
```

Also computer crashing like e.g. power outage etc...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of this error by a combination of the answers here plus some more:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Delete the .suo file
4. Re-open Visual Studio - the same error
5. Edit the .csproj file - >go to the
   ProjectExtensions/VisualStudio/FlavorProperties, delete the entire
   FlavorProperties element.
6. Reload the project

Answer (score -1):

try

- reopening solution
- renaming the solution file (.sln) to something else
- deleting of "ProjectExtensions"