# VS2015 : Unable to start debugging. The startup project could not be launched. & “the operation could not be completed” error at the same time

Tags: visual-studio

This morning , out of nowhere faced this two problems.
Below are the screenshots -

[image]
[image: When I wanted to build the project]

Searched around and saw two similar problems posted in StackOverflow but individually. 
[Visual Studio popup: "the operation could not be completed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079466/visual-studio-popup-the-operation-could-not-be-completed)
And 
[Unable to start debugging. The startup project could not be launched. VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612888/unable-to-start-debugging-the-startup-project-could-not-be-launched-vs2015)

> But in my case, I got both at the same time.

Solution : A simple restart made the problems disappear.

My Question is , made this both problems occur out of nowhere and why they disappeared at the same time? 
the answer probably be .suo file in my project got changed. (in the first Question of the link)
But what exactly can make changes to my .suo file anyways? 
Can any other process make changes to this file automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution :*** A simple restart of **Visual Studio** made the problems disappear.

P.S : Last day I was stuck at ***git*** I suspect it might have changed the .suo file in my project. That's why I was unable to build or start the project