# Getting an Unable to start debugging ... startup project could not be launched. Why?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, azure-devops

I'm writing a new UWP app, using Azure DevOps with Git for source control. I'm doing development between my laptop and my desktop. I can debug the project fine on my laptop, but I cannot on my desktop. When I try I get this error message:

> Unable to start debugging. The startup project could not be launched.

That's all it says. I started this project on my laptop, pushed it to Azure DevOps and have been developing on both the desktop and laptop. This is the first time I've tried debugging on both machines. Like I said, it worked fine on the laptop, but failed with the above error on the desktop. Don't understand what I've done wrong, but guess that I have. I'm using VS 2017, version 15.9.4

The application I'm working on is not a Core application. For that reason, I do not believe that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210498/unable-to-start-debugging-the-startup-project-cannot-be-launched) elsewhere on Stack Overflow applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210498/unable-to-start-debugging-the-startup-project-cannot-be-launched)

Comment: I saw the post on Stack Overflow that you referred to, Ken. I didn't think it applied because it was for a Core application. The one I'm working on is not a Core application.

Comment: Did you also follow the link that the OP of that question provided?

Comment: Did you add any branches? What branch are you trying to debug? Did you select a proper project to start debugging? (right click -> set up as startup project). Are you sure you fetched everything from your DevOps git?

Comment: Ken, I can get into the project. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting it, but that's what I thought the OP to mean by launching the project. Michal, I have not branched the project.

Comment: Could your share a simple sample with us ?